# Remove space and nulls from list in PowerQuery

Tags: excel, powerquery

Is there a way to replace this `(List.RemoveNulls(_))` with somthing like  `(each _<> "" and _ <> null)`

I tried this and it did not work

```
Table.RenameColumns(
    Table.CombineColumns(BlanksToNull,mergeHeaders[List Of Headers For Concatenation], each Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.RemoveNulls(_)),"Merged")
,{{"Merged",newMergedHeader}})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about changing

```
Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.RemoveNulls(_)),"Merged")
```

to

```
Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None)(List.Difference(_, {" ",null})),"Merged")
```

Comment: Thanks again, that worked great.  I will read up on `List.Difference`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-difference

Comment: you could also use List.RemoveMatchingItems() or List.RemoveItems()